# How to manage multiple monitors with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have five monitors connected to my docking station at work.  When I connect my computer I have to go into the Resolution settings and enable each monitor.  This is a result of the USB video card drivers conflicting with my NVidia driver at start up. I've updated all of the drivers but the NVidia driver always crashes the USB drivers on start up.  Once the boot up is complete, I can enable the monitors one by one which causes no problem.

I am looking for a powershell script that I can run after the computer boots up that will enable each monitor.

Comment: I don't know exactly how to do it, but I can push you in the right direction! You can get a list of the monitors from [EnumDisplayDevices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162609%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and you can turn the monitors on and off via [ChangeDisplaySettingEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183413%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Take a look at [this AutoHotkey forum post](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/20084-secondary-monitor/) to possibly help you out with more information.

Comment: Thanks for pushing me in that direction.  I wasn't able to get this to work but at least I it points me into a different direction.